# Algebraically Evaluate Limit

Tags: geometry, limits, pi

The following function is half the perimeter of a regular $n$-gon with circumradius $1$ where $x$ is the number of subdivisions in half following a hexagon (when $x=1$, $n$ is $12$):

$p(x)=6 (2^{x-1})\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3(2^x)})}$

Geometrically and numerically, it is obvious that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} p(x) = \pi$.

**How can you prove this algebraically?**

As a bonus question, is there any closed form expression with no trig functions that approaches $\pi$? This came up in an attempt to find one. It failed, but I did find out an interesting recurrence relation:

$q(x)=\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3(2^x)})}$

satisfies:

$q(x+1)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-q(x)^2}}$

at least when $x$ is a non-negative integer.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by closed form: $\dfrac{(n!)^2 }{2 n+\frac13} \left(\dfrac e n\right)^{2n} \to \pi$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure if there's a more specific name for what I'm looking for but it doesn't include factorials. Maybe closed form with only elementary functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a couple algebraic manipulations to get: $p(x)=6\sqrt{2}\cdot 2^{x-1}\sqrt{1-\cos\left(2\cdot \frac\pi{12\cdot2^{x-1}}\right)}$

Now, if we let $y=2^{x-1}$, then $y\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and so our limit is equal to $L=\lim_{y\to\infty}6\sqrt 2\cdot y\sqrt{1-\cos\left(2\cdot\frac\pi{12y}\right)}$

But $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$ and so $L=\lim_{y\to\infty}6\sqrt{2}\cdot y\cdot\sqrt{2\sin^2\left(\frac\pi{12y}\right)}=\lim_{y\to\infty}12y\sin\left(\frac\pi{12y}\right)$

One last substitution in case it isn't clear yet, $t=\frac1y$ so that $t\to0$ as $y\to\infty$:

$$L=12\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi{12}t\right)}t=12\cdot\frac\pi{12}=\boxed{\pi}$$

As for your bonus question, it really does depend on what you mean by "closed form." I would argue that $\pi=\frac{\ln(-1)}i$ is a closed form expression. $\pi=2\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$ is also perfectly valid and can be converted into a limit of a Riemann sum. Generally, however, the fundamental property of $\pi$ as $\frac1{2i}$ of the period of $\exp$ means that you'll probably want to invoke the complex exponential (or the trig functions that are just the complex exponential in disguise) in your "closed-form" limits for $\pi$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! For the bonus question I'm looking for something like the limit that defines $e$, although intuitively to me it seems like no such expression exists. Including $ln(-1)$ is definitely cheating though, lol.

Comment: @TigerGold Yeah, I know it is, but at the same time, I would argue that what you include and what you don't include is totally arbitrary. But if you define "closed-form" as "addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, real-valued exponentials, and the real logarithm, all possibly composed and applied to rationals," I think the answer is that there is no such limit that will approach $\pi$. I have no idea how to prove such a thing, though, as I don't know of any active research studying "elementary functions" that doesn't allow complex log.

Comment: I agree with Benjamin, both with regards to how he answered the question about the limit, and also with regards to whether there is any expression using only real-value exponentials, logarithms, and rational functions that approaches π. π can only be defined in terms of elementary functions by the trigonometric functions.